# Trouble printing from Canon iP 1980

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I've been having problem printing with my Canon Pixma iP1980 on Ubuntu 16.04. I've been using Gutenprint, but the printer just blinks and then does nothing. When I check the status message, it says something about missing filter.

Here's a list of things I've tried:

1. Removing and re-adding the same printer driver.
2. Removing and installing other variant of the printer driver from the database.
3. Purging and reinstalling `openprinting-gutenprint`.
4. Grabbing `cnijfilter-common` and `cnijfilter-ip1900` from Canon website (By far this is the most promising, but it requires libpopt0 v1.7 which I don't know how to install).

Anything else I can try?

Comment: so that is a venerable 9yr old printer; it is going well; when did it last work well? we have libpopt0 on our system already; will it install with `sudo apt install libpopt0` typed into a terminal;

Comment: @pdc It runs well on Windows. On Ubuntu, it's another story. `libpopt0` is available, but only v1.16 while the `cnijfilter-common` requires >=1.7. I ended up using a third-party repo which I'm going to discuss in an answer I'm about to write.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up installing the driver from [this repository on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~inameiname/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

It provides drivers for a number of Canon printers, along with some other software packages. Here's how to do it:

1. If there's any driver installed previously, remove it from the Printers list.
2. Launch the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for shortcut).
3. Type in `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inameiname/stable` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Provide your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Type in `sudo apt-get update` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Provide your password again *if* prompted.
5. Type in `sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip1900-series-32` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Again, you might have to provide your password. Reply with `y` if asked to confirm installation.
6. Turn on the printer and connect it to the PC. Then check the Printers list. A printer called "Canon-iP1900-series" should automatically be added shortly.

And that's it. You can now use  the iP1980.

Comment: glad it is working; seems to me that is the identical driver one can get from the Canon website http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100159101.html that is cnijfilter-ip1900series_3.00-1_i386.deb but I guess some might worry about adding a ppa that seems absolutely benign but is relatively unknown

Comment: @pdc I tried, but the dependency tricks I used on Lucid don't work anymore. Now it's not just the `libcupsys` thing, but also `libpopt0` whose specific version I have trouble finding and `libtiff4` which is can't be installed on Xenial from official repos.

Comment: Debian is a good source; for libtiff4, go here https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libtiff4 and scroll down the page till you get to amd64 or i386 and for libpopt0 see if Debian can help you https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=opt I do find it strange you feel you need >1.17 as it is such an old driver ie nearly 10yrs old: Debian offer 1.16 libpopt0 for recent releases